# From timer interrupt to the rerun of main function (PIC16f877)

Tags: pic, c

I'm working on a basic project for a security system with PIC16f877 in MikroC, and I had a problem concerning the timer interrupt. I want the interruption to be cancelled when a chosen amount of time is reached and I want the program to rerun since the beginning(starting from zero). This is what I have done so far(thanks in advance guys):

```
    void InitTimer1() 
 {

       T1CON          = 0x39;
       TMR1IF_bit     = 0;
       TMR1H          = 0x0B;
       TMR1L          = 0xDB;
       TMR1IE_bit     = 1;
       INTCON         = 0xC0;
 }

 void Interrupt()
 {
 if (TMR1IF_bit){
  TMR1IF_bit = 0;
  TMR1H      = 0x0B;
  TMR1L      = 0xDB;
  time++;
  if(time == 38){   //20 == 5 sec, 38 == 10 sec   
  PORTB.RB1=0;

  //i want the interruption to be cancelled here and rerun 
  // the program since the begining of main function
          }
              }
}


   void main()
  {  //declaraion ...

  //i want the program to restart from loop
   LOOP :
   //some code

       else
       {
        InitTimer1();
        // some code running with the interrupt
        //if condition then rerun(no need to w8 for the 10seconds set in the interrupt)
                  {goto LOOP  ;}

                  }while (1);
       }

   }
```

Comment: What is that `else` doing?  Labels in C aren't evil but that's not a good use of one.  This would be a lot easier to read with proper indentation.

Comment: The standard way is to write an incorrect sequence to the watchdog register, to force a reset of the whole MCU including hardware.

Answer (score 1):

A number of problems:

Your commenting is abysmal, to the point of irresponsibility.  Loading fixed constants like 39h, DBh, etc, into registers without any explanation of what the bits mean or even the overall intent is ridiculous.  You should be ashamed of yourself for dumping crap like that in front of others.

What's the point of resetting timer 1 to a fixed value in the interrupt if you're going to restart the program, which will then initialize timer 1 anyway?

The variable TIME is never defined nor initialized.  You seem to want to restart the program when it reaches 38, but without it ever being initialized there is no guarantee when that will be.

To restart the program, just GOTO 0.  I don't know the conventions of that compiler, but to be safe you should set PCLATH to 0 before the jump.  Otherwise, the jump could end up at 800h, 1000h, or 1800h instead.

Comment: If using `GOTO 0` the coder should take extra care to ensure all initialisation is done correctly.  The 16F series seems to lack a software reset (except by using the WDT) and `GOTO 0` won't set registers to their POR values.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specifics of your controller, but I doubt that he will have something like software reset. My first thought would be setting a "restart" flag in the isr and checking that from the main loop. If it is set, do a goto main. This solution however has the downside of doing that jump not immediately. You have to wait until the program reaches the check for the flag.

Second thought would be assembly. I can't write it, but I could imagine that you could clear your call stack and reset the program pointer to the beginning of main. Not sure of that though.

Edit: third thought: let the watchdog reset yourself.